# How to round time to the nearest quarter hour in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to round time to the nearest quarter hour in a word document.  I am not very good at coding.

After a fair bit of searching I have found some vba code but it doesn't quite work.  The code is:

```
Sub Time()
Dim num() As String
Dim tod() As String
Dim temp As String

num = Split(Time, ":")
tod = Split(num(2), " ")

If Val(num(1)) < 15 Then
    temp = "00"
ElseIf Val(num(1)) < 30 Then
    temp = "15"
ElseIf Val(num(1)) < 45 Then
    temp = "30"
ElseIf Val(num(1)) < 60 Then
    temp = "45"
End If
gettime = num(0) + ":" + temp + ":00 " + tod(1)

End Function
End Sub
```

When I try to run it I get a message:

> "Compile Error: Expected function or variable"

and "Time" on the fifth line of the code is highlighted which I think is where the program stops running.

The rest of the code in the form is as follows:

**This module doesn't affect the time rounding issue but I am including it so as not to leave anything out.**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClusterCheck()

Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, iCluster As Integer, bResult As Boolean
Dim sFieldNameNo As String, sName As String

    On Error Resume Next    ' If the first formfield is a checkbox, this will bypass the error that Word returns
    
    sName = Selection.FormFields(1).Name    ' Get the name of the formfield
    bResult = ActiveDocument.FormFields(sName).CheckBox.Value    ' Get the result of the current formfield
    sFieldNameNo = Number(sName)    ' Get generic number
    sName = Left(sName, Len(sName) - Len(sFieldNameNo))    ' Get generic name
    
    ' Determine how many fields are within the cluster group
    iCluster = 1
    Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(sName & iCluster) = False
        iCluster = iCluster + 1
    Loop
    iCluster = iCluster - 1
    
    ' If the check field is true, turn all of the other check fields to false
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If bResult = True Then
        For k = 1 To iCluster
            If k <> sFieldNameNo Then ActiveDocument.FormFields(sName & k).Result = False
        Next
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

**This is the Number module:**

```
Option Explicit

Function Number(ByVal sNumber As String) As String

' This module finds the form fields number within the field name

    ' Loops through the field name until it only has the number
    Do Until IsNumeric(sNumber) = True Or sNumber = ""
        sNumber = Right(sNumber, Len(sNumber) - 1)
    Loop
    
    Number = sNumber

End Function
```

**This is the protection module:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Protect()

    ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="wup13", NoReset:=True, Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields
End Sub

Sub Unprotect()

    ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="wup13"
End Sub
```

**This is the code that activates on opening and closing the document:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Document_Open()

    ' Zooms to page width, turns on Hidden Text, and turns off ShowAll and Table Gridlines
    With ActiveWindow.View
        .Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitBestFit
        .ShowHiddenText = True
        .TableGridlines = False
        .ShowAll = False
    End With
    
    Options.UpdateFieldsAtPrint = False

End Sub

Sub Document_Close()

    ' Turn on ShowAll and Table Gridlines
    With ActiveWindow.View
        .ShowAll = True
        .TableGridlines = True
    End With
    
    Options.UpdateFieldsAtPrint = True
    
End Sub
```

That's all the code in the form. I am not great at VBA but am hoping I can solve this issue (with a little help).

DETAILS OF EXTRA DUTY FORM

Persons details
Family name:
Given name(s):

Level:
No.:
Location:

Cost Centre Code:

Time worked
Were any days of the extra duty performed on a designated public/show holiday?  Yes  0  No  0
If yes enter holiday date/details:

Time commenced: [Text Form Field]
Date:

Time ceased:    [Text Form Field]
Date:

Total Overtime claimed:

Are you a shift worker? Yes  0     No  0

Details of extra duty performed:

Vehicle details
Car:  Yes  0     No  0
Motorcycle:  Yes  0     No  0
Registration no.:
Fleet no.:

Stationary vehicle hours:
Yes  0     No  0  (only use for stationary duties)

Vehicle odometer start:
Odometer finish:
Total kms:

Client’s details
Company/Organisation name:
Phone no.:

Contact name:

Job no.:

Payment for special services
Was payment received in advance?    Yes  0      No  0

If Yes– Amount:
Receipt no.:
Date:

If No–  Amount:
Invoice no.:
Date:

I,            , certify the above information to be true

(Signature)     (Date)
Manager certification (Checked with roster and certified correct)

(Signature)     (Date)

Comment: Your sub is named `Time`. What do you expect `Split(Time, ":")` to do in a sub named `Time`?

Comment: Appears to be mostly http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?154671-round-time-to-the-nearest-15-minutes&p=881042&viewfull=1#post881042 but missing `Public Function gettime(time As String) As String`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the line of code Split(Time, ":") does in the module but that is where the program stops executing.

Comment: When the line Public Function gettime(Time As String) As String is included in the module it stops executing at the start.  The first line Sub Time() is highlighted.  I probably should have left that in so you could see it but the code still doesn't work with that in.  Yes I found the code at vbforums but unfortunately it doesn't quite work for me. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code from vbforums gives me a subscript out of range error when used as recommended.

In the VBA IDE you can get explanations of what keywords do by placing the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1.  This will bring up the MS help page for that particular keyword.

In the OP code the main procedure is 'Time'.  This will cause problems for VBA because this is the same as the Time keyword so we would effectively be saying

```
time(time)
```

and VBA will stop with an error because the second use of time will be interpreted as the sub time and not the  VBA time function so you will get the error message 'Argument not optional'.

The code below will provide what the OP has requested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_gettime()
Dim myTime                  As String

    myTime = Now()
    Debug.Print myTime
    Debug.Print Format(myTime, "hh:mm:ss")
    Debug.Print gettime(Format(myTime, "hh:mm:ss"))

    ' without the format statement we should also get the date

    myTime = Now()
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print myTime
    Debug.Print gettime(myTime)

End Sub

Public Function gettime(this_time As String) As String
Dim myTimeArray()                       As String
Dim myQuarterHour                       As String

    myTimeArray = Split(this_time, ":")

    ' Note that myTimeArray has not been converted to numbers
    ' Comparison of strings works by comparing the ascii values of each character
    ' in turn until the requested logic is satisfied
    Select Case myTimeArray(1)
        Case Is < "15"
            myQuarterHour = "00"
        Case Is < "30"
            myQuarterHour = "15"
         Case Is < "45"
             myQuarterHour = "30"
         Case Is < "60"
             myQuarterHour = "45"
         Case Else
            Debug.Print "More than 60 minutes in the hour??"
    End Select
    gettime = myTimeArray(0) + ":" + myQuarterHour + ":00 "
End Function
```

Comment: I do not get any error messages now but unfortunately that code is not executing in the form.  I have text form fields in the document for users to enter time commenced and time ceased.  In the Text Form Field Options box I have set your macro 'test_gettime' to run on Entry and/or on Exit.  (I have tried all combinations of this).  What I want to happen is when someone enters a time (say 10:40) that this will automatically round to 10:45 when they tab out of the form field.  (The document is password protected so they can just tab through it entering data and times etc. in various fields).

Comment: Do I perhaps need to run a macro to unprotect the document so that this code can then execute?

Comment: HI Tony B

I'd love to help you more but it seems your level of understanding of VBA is just too low.  For example, the macro test_gettime is just a demonstration of how the function gettime works.  This is also the first time you mentioned that the code has to run in a form as the consequence of an event.  If you were able to post the current code in your form then we may be able to help more.

Comment: Hi TonyB  I have reviewed the updated code you provided but there is no place to use a time value nor any line that creates the form you refer to.  You need to check the Class and Forms folders for additional code. Select the forms Folder then click on the form to get the view of the form. Then View.Code to switch from the view of the Form to the actual code that sits behind the form.

Comment: Hi Steve I have pasted the form at the end of the code in my question.  It is pretty raw and unformatted as I couldn't copy the actual word file into this forum. You will see though that there are 2 lines for Time Commenced and Time Ceased.  What I want is when the person enters a time in the Text form field in those lines is for that to be auto rounded to the nearest quarter hour.  I would like to attach the actual word document as that would make things clearer.  I hope this explains more what I need. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: TonyB. You posted the form not the code behind the form. Please read up on how to edit the code of a form.  You will then be able to see where the input for the two fields you indicate is taken and apply the gettime function at those two points.

Comment: Hi Steve.  I am not sure what you mean as I have pasted all the VBA code above the form in the question window. ie the various modules from the forms VBA project window. Is that the code you mean?  I am not aware of any other code.  I would like to post the actual word document as I think that would help but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: TonyB.  I'm sorry but as I indicated earlier you don't seem to have sufficient VBA knowledge for me to help you.   As for sending files then googling' Stackoverflow attach files' is a fairly straightforward query.

Comment: Hi Steve I think you maybe right this problem is above my knowledge of VBA.  I thought it would be easier than it has turned out.  I will try an improve my knowledge and return to it later.  Thanks for your help though.